# Landscape page layout using Rails and Spreadsheet

Tags: ruby, spreadsheet, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm using [Spreadsheet](https://github.com/voraz/spreadsheet) to generate reports in application and I need to set page layout to landscape when file will be printed (customer request).

Is there any way to do this on the application level?